# CAS Authentication get data

Tags: php, authentication, curl, web, cas

I'm trying to pull user information from a server that's using CAS to authenticate.  I can already log the user in and get an authentication key back from the server, but when I try to get an user data from the server I get back a 401 error.

```
// Generate time stamp information
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $timestamp = date(YmdGis);

    // Generate hash key
    $hashKey = hash_hmac(SHA1, $cURL . $date, $_SESSION['AuthKey']);

    // Initialize and execute cURL
    $url = "https://d1m.server.edu/API/v2.0/Student/CourseSections";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: " . $_SESSION['userid'] . ":" . $hashKey . ":" . $timestamp));

    if( ! $result = curl_exec($ch)) 
    { 
        trigger_error(curl_error($ch)); 
    } 
    curl_close($ch);

    $response = json_decode($result);
    if(isset($response->{'StatusCode'}))
    {
        return "Failed to connect to server with error code " . $response->{'StatusCode'};
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        return var_dump($response);
        // TODO: print course information in user-friendly format
        exit();
    }
```

This php code is something that I converted from an existing implementation in java, which I know works, found here:

```
String cURL = "https://d1m.server.edu/API/v2.0/Student/CourseSections";
            SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            simpledateformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            String date = Authenticate.getUTCdatetimeAsString();
            String s2 = cURL + date;
            String s3 = "";
            String key = Authkey;
            s3 = s4 = Authenticate.generateHash(key, String.valueOf(cURL) + date).replace("\n", "");
            String userid = u;
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(cURL);
            httpget.setHeader("Authorization", String.valueOf(userid) + ":" + s4 + ":" + date);
            inputstream = defaulthttpclient.execute((HttpUriRequest)httpget).getEntity().getContent();
            root = jp.parse((Reader)new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
            JsonArray jArray = root.getAsJsonArray();
```